# Datatable Custom Coloring

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to add custom coloring in a data table in PF 2.2.1:

xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable style="width: 100%;" id="dTable" var="tt" value="#{aList}" paginator="true" rows="15"
                                 selection="#{selected}" selectionMode="single" 
                                 onRowSelectUpdate="mf:tabcontent" 
rowStyleClass="#{tt.state.intValue() le 2 ? 'waiting' : null}"
```

POJO:

```
private Byte state;
```

css:

```
.waiting{
    background-image: none !important;
    color: black !important;
}
```

I cleared the cache of the browser, refresh the page several times but still no good. What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you want to color the background of the cell?

try adding `background-color` attribute as well, like this

```
    background-color: #6CE26C !important;
```

complete :

```
.waiting{
    background-color: #6CE26C !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: adding background-color, weirdly, solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `color` is the font color.